# Super Custom Search Form that I'm trying to implement into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

So, I have a search form that only searches for Instagram user info located in the header here ([myinstadp.com](http://myinstadp.com)). I want to implement it on WordPress, preferably in the header also. I have access to the files that make this happen, I'm just not sure which files to put together or if I need to just build a new search form that can do the same thing (but then I'm not there yet as a developer - so nah!).

The theme I'm using is Essence Pro on Genesis.

How in the world can I make this happen? I've tried everything.

Sincerely,
a newbie

Answer (score 0):

There is very little documentation for that theme but I would suggest some options are available to you.

You could:
Create a template part and add it to a page or child theme.
Create a plugin that adds a shortcode with the scripts you want then add that shortcode to the template via the do_shortcode() function in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks. How would I know which scripts? Newbie to this :)

Comment: The javascript that runs on the form submission. The script block line starts at line 527. This will probably need a bit of reworking though. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the help.